# ANOVA planned (a priori) tests

Tags: anova, apriori

Can anybody tell me which ANOVA planned (a priori) tests exist? 
Which are their characteristics? How and when are they used?
As I´m beginner in this area it would be also useful in someone could point me to relevant literature on this question?